# GA4 Receiving event name but no event value

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, web-vitals, core-web-vitals

I am trying to implement Web Vitals monitoring with GTM and GA4.

To do this I am using custom GTM template created by Simo Ahava. [LINK](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-core-web-vitals-in-ga4-with-google-tag-manager/)

From what I see, I have done this implementation correctly - I can see the variables I need to be pushed to the data layer when previewing

[image: GTM Preview Data Layer for LCP]

This is how I push them to GA4:
[image: Trigger config in GTM]

Now the issues are in the GA4 end. I can see the events populating to GA4. However, when I go to Analysis Hub and try to create a custom report, I can get the counts of the events, but their values show up as 0

[image: GA4 Analysis Hub Report]

When using the DebugView in GA4, I can indeed see that the values are getting pushed correctly

[image: GA4 DebugView for LCP metric]

So my question is... What am I doing wrong here? Why are the values not showing up?

EDIT: I have tried more things. Still not working but wanted to give you and update.

I have added custom metric and dimension to GA4 in hopes to fix this issue.

A custom metric for web vitals value
[image: Custom metric setup for web_vitals_value]

A custom dimension for web vitals name
[image: Custom dimension for web_vitals_name]

I tried all the possible combos:

1. Dimension: Event Name (default one), metric: Web Vitals Value
2. Dimension: Web Vitals Name (custom), metric: Web Vitals Value
3. Dimension: Web Vitals Name (custom), metric: Event Value

None of them worked. However, here is something peculiar I found. When using Web Vitals Name as dimension, I cannot pick up names either. This leads me to believe I am doing some sort of error in the first place.

[image]

Maybe this will help somewhat....

Comment: The report can't select today, so you have to wait a day to see any changes.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am aware of this. The data had been populating for almost two weeks when I was writing this question. That's when I set up the GTM tags and confirmed that data is coming to GA4 using debugview

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for the missing values?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding currency to the data? Not sure it works but seems possible to be the error - I've just tried it now after [seeing this post](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-mistakes/).

Answer (score 0):

- Double check those custom definitions you setup, to match the parameter name in GA4 (matching case sensitivity)
- make sure your GTM container is published
- Fire test events on your website
- wait the full 48 hours to make sure they are in GA4 (otherwise you will be getting that frustrating (not set) error)
- Make sure your exploration data range is pulling the latest data.